# GLReadPixels returns a single,incorrect, value repeated over and over

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently trying to write a simple screen capture application with OpenGL.
My current source looks like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
int nWidth = 1920; // use these dimentions, We'll work work out a calculation to get the real dimentions later.
int nHeight = 1080;
unsigned char* buffer;//declair the buffer here plox
int size = nWidth*nHeight*3; //number of bytes the image will take up.
char input;

buffer = (GLubyte *)malloc(size); // acctually assign some RAM for the program



glReadBuffer ( GL_BACK ); //which buffer we are reading from.

glReadPixels ( 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buffer); 

const char* out=(const char*)buffer;

std::ofstream outfile ("out.crw",std::ifstream::binary);

outfile.write (out,size);
cout << out;
cin>> input;
return;

}
```

It produces no errors. Although, the return values from GLReadPixels are character "í" repeated over and over in the output file. The hex value for "í" is "CD", "CD" is red 205 in colour values, so it seems to atleast output a colour.

I was expecting multiple values to be returned indicating an image containing multiple colours. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You never set up OpenGL and you never render anything. Have you left out some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot caputre the screen via OpenGL, even if you actually would set up a GL context. You can only read back what you did render with the GL. Everything outside of the framebuffer of the GL is just not accessible that way. You will need to use some platform-specific APIs to do screen captures.

Comment: Ah, i guess thats where i went wrong then. I had no idea that GLReadPixels would only capture GL rendered content. I thought it would give me the contents of the VRAM/framebuffer. As someone new to OpenGL its not very clear in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced this is true. The main reason it's not advisable to read the front buffer in OpenGL afaik is because other drawing calls (e.g. from other apps) could have drawn over it, that seems about the exact opposite of what you're saying.

Comment: @KillianDS - The key here is "could have". There is no guarantee you will get anything that makes sense.

Comment: @KillianDS: There used to be some screen capture programs that epxloit the fact that a newly created Window + OpenGL context will have the previous contents of the framebuffer being in uninitialized memory. However this only works with non-composited windowing systems. Modern graphics systems are composited and this trick no longer works.

Comment: @ananthonline yes, undefined, it "could" work, while this answer states it will with 100% certainty not work, I think even this is undefined (could be wrong though), should have made that clear in my previous comment.